# Почему не выводится Toast?

Tags: java, android

Есть Presenter, а в нем код:

```
  public void onResponse(Call<LoginUserResponse> call, Response<LoginUserResponse> response) {
            if(response.body().getResult().equals("true")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(loginActivity, ActivityFragments.class);
                intent.putExtra("id",response.body().getId());
                loginActivity.startActivity(intent);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(loginActivity,"Вы ввели неправильный логин или пароль",Toast.LENGTH_LONG); 
            }
```

По дебагеру прошелся, он до строчки с Тостом доходит и выполняет его(но на экране ничего не отображается). В чем проблема?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вы создали Toast, а вывести его забыли. Добавьте вызов метода `show()` :

```
Toast.makeText(loginActivity,"Вы ввели неправильный логин или пароль",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Не подскажете, новый Toast добавили, когда он снизу выскакивает, как он называется?

Comment: [Snackbar](https://material.io/guidelines/components/snackbars-toasts.html)

Comment: если используете Android studio, там есть Template для вывода тоста. Просто печатаете Toast и нажимаете Enter.